# slidershow in my website has conflict with other js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, prototypejs, slideshow

it's seems that it has conflict between Jquery version 10  and prototype.js file. how can i solve this conflict.
this is all of my jquery file that i have used in to my project

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <!--    start slider show    -->
   <script src="http://www.gametap-shop.com/skins/bad/js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.gametap-shop.com/skins/bad/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script src="http://www.gametap-shop.com/skins/bad/js/carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="http://www.gametap-shop.com/Js/gameShopEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.gametap-shop.com/Js/tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End slider show  -->  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom_scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$ = jQuery;
 jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function ($) {
       $("#mainMenu").menu( { position: { my: "left top", at: "center bottom" } } );  
    });


</script>
```

and of course i put [my website here](http://game.hisend.ir/page.html)
and my slidershow that has problem is below the yellow box..
i am also put the whole problem [in my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hussein39/ZYH8x/)

Comment: remove line $ = jQuery;

Comment: i did but it doesn't helpful, the problem is still resisted.

Comment: http://vanilla-js.com

Comment: @bjb568 this is unlikely to help in getting a jQuery plugin to work...

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course not, I was suggesting an alternative.